# Rotation of div containing html5 elemets (e.g. SVG, canvas) in ie9 doesn't show div properly

Tags: html, canvas, svg, internet-explorer-9

I've tried using the filter attribute to rotate a div, this works well until the div is comprised of an SVG element, which results in a rotated div with the SVG not being shown (with the exception of images).

e.g.
style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.86602540, M12=0.50000000, M21=-0.50000000,M22=0.86602540,sizingMethod='auto expand');"

Am I doing something wrong, or doesn't IE9 support this mix?

Thanks in advance,
Oren

p.s. in case you were wondering why do I prefer to rotate the containing div, the answer is that the div contains more than just the SVG, e.g. inputs.

Comment: You know IE9 is in beta, right? :)

Comment: IE9 doesn't support CSS transforms because CSS transformation specification isn't final but still, in fact, just a draft.

Answer (score 0):

According to [www.devsource.com](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Architecture/Microsoft-Touts-HTML5-SVG-Support-in-IE9-Platform-Preview/), Ted Johnson (founder of Visio and partner program manager for Internet Explorer) stated:

> IE9 will not support SVG fonts,
>   declarable animation or **filter
>   effects**

:(

I'll mark this as the correct answer when permitted, since this won't change for some time (please let me know if I should do otherwise).

Comment: svg filter effects !== microsoft proprietary filter effects like those mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx This is, in your case, a good thing, because it means that what you are trying to do might actually still work, because it's inconclusive whether these proprietary filter effects will be supported in IE9. I don't have a Win7 box, so I won't be able to test this myself, unfortunately, but I would recommend trying some of the examples at the linked-to page to see to what level MS filter effects might be supported in IE9.

Comment: Another thing you can try is using a div with an SVG element, and inside of the SVG element use a foreignObject element, and inside of that put the div and all of the stuff you wish to rotate. This is a way to apply SVG transformations to HTML content, and you see this technique being applied a lot in demos.

Comment: Thanks! regarding foreignObject, it doesn't work on ie9's beta, and according to http://schmerg.com/svg-support-in-ie9-close-but-should-try-harde won't be supported.